# Multiple external packages with same name

Tags: python, django

I have a problem, where I have two packages that I use quite often, in different sites, with the same name. Namely, they are django-simple-captcha and django-recaptcha. They are both just called captcha.

In addition, these are shared between several people who may work on them, so I can't just have them as different names without it messing up between people.

Is there some way to solve this?

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? They have different options for relative imports.

Comment: What problem exactly do you need to solve? It sounds messy and potentially confusing, but if each site you're on only has access to one of them, there are no path or loading conflicts, right? Do you have scripts that must run on both sites, or ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly that no projects that need both exist, then use [Virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org). You should anyway.  It creates a separate environment for every project and completely eliminates conflicts between libraries needed by different projects.

Answer (score 0):

If those different sites use the same controller (file.py) then the packages must have different name.